# Vagrant is not port forwarding with VirtualBox and PuPHPet

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, vagrantfile, puphpet

## Problem

I cannot connect to my virtual machine's environment, despite using an accepted private network and forwarded ports.

### Description

**System**

- MAC OSX 10.9.3
- Vagrant 1.6.3
- VirtualBox 4.3.12
- [Vagrantfile file](https://gist.github.com/cee570ce069dbb3256ad)
- [Puphpet file](https://gist.github.com/ca6f2fbcc352cca6f424)
- Cisco AnyConnect VPN
- Using Private Company Network
- [ifconfig results](https://gist.github.com/ff6d8918b82b6cca0e25)
- [Virtual Host file](https://gist.github.com/KLVTZ/ba4e6c1f00b032764c29) for Web Project.

Upon `vagrant up`, I `vagrant ssh` into my virtualbox. The following request work as expected:

```
[06:04 PM]-[vagrant@precise64]-[~]
$ curl -v 192.168.56.101
* About to connect() to 192.168.56.101 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.56.101... connected
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: 192.168.56.101
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 09 Jul 2014 18:05:05 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu)
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 481
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
* Closing connection #0

[06:05 PM]-[vagrant@precise64]-[~]
$ curl -v playworldsystems.dev
* About to connect() to playworldsystems.dev port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.56.101... connected
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: playworldsystems.dev
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 09 Jul 2014 18:05:52 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.14-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 122
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
<
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'hello'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
* Closing connection #0
</pre>
```

However, when I try both commands from within my HOST terminal, I receive the following error:

```
curl -v 192.168.56.101
* About to connect() to 192.168.56.101 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.56.101...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fc6f1000000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fc6f1000000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Failed connect to 192.168.56.101:80; Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.56.101:80; Operation timed out
☁  ~  curl -v playworldsystems.dev
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fdbe9803000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fdbe9803000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to playworldsystems.dev port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.56.101...
* Failed connect to playworldsystems.dev:80; Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to playworldsystems.dev:80; Operation timed out
```

Even after trying cURLing from both port `6969` and `8080`, I still have no success. I've used random IP Addresses as well as Ports. I've tried altering my virtual host to other port numbers. Nothing seems to work. I will mention that when first starting out, I noticed that this vagrant setup has worked --both only twice. Each time it was working, i would `vagrant suspend` and `vagrant up` the next morning to find that my prior solution is no longer working.

Perhaps this fact is what makes this process so frustrating. I want to get of MAMP for my current projects but fear that it is either my work machine's settings that are interfering or perhaps some other application or network related issue. I'm unsure what steps to take and am looking forward to any and all solutions.

Comment: I think puphpet is f-ed up.. same problem here, thinking of switching to protobox

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos I'll be sure to check it out! Haha but yeah the below answer fixed my problem. Check out: https://gist.github.com/dad8ad0c459ba77304a7 for my setup. Also a quick script to compensate for ever changing ifconfig eth0 and en0 addresses (wired and wireless) that I wrote whenever the broadcast failed: https://github.com/KLVTZ/dotfiles/blob/master/mac/zshrc#L142-166

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a few tips/pointers.

1. check that the firewall rules are not blocking the ports,  if all else fails, just disable it for testing  "iptables -F"
2. make sure ports are forwarded correctly https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html
   so what you want for http is   host:8080  guest:80
3. sometimes your IP address changes on your host ( for example, acquiring new dhcp or joining new network home/work/vpn )
   check that you can ping your VM guest from your host via the correct IP from the correct adapter.  On the host run "ifconfig -a"   (on the mac there should be some  en0 for ethernet and en1 for airport)  if you can ping the vm guest, then you can hit the web server via port 8080 (  http://mylocal.dev:8080/ )   provided of course that you edited your /etc/hosts to point your vhost to the above mentioned IP address.